# Is the maximum function Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $f(x)=\max_{1\le i\le N}\{x_i\}$, where $x$ is an $N$-dimensional vector. Is the function $f$ Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I know it is when $f(x)=\max\{|x_i|\}$. I'm still struggling with the case without the absolute value sign, though.

Comment: @YYM: Have you written out what it would mean for your function to be Lipschitz? If so, could you please say where you're stuck? If not, perhaps try the case $N = 2$ first and see what you find.

Comment: @Vim, Could you please give me some hints or guidelines for the proof for case with an absolute sign? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably say what metric you are using on $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, x belongs to R^N (R_{+}^{N}).

Comment: @YYM Yes, but the definition of [Lipschitz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) involves a metric. You never said what metric you are using on the space $\mathbb R^N$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak most commonly it's Euclidean metric. Maybe op has only learned about vector norms but not so far as metric spaces.

Comment: @YYM the hint (which I think is sufficient for you to kick off with) is the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 4):

You have $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |\max_{1\le i \le N} x_i - \max_{1\le i \le N} y_i| \overset{(*)}\le \max_{1\le i \le N} |x_i-y_i| = \|x-y\|_\infty.$$ 
So if you are using the metric
$$d_\infty(x,y) = \|x-y\|_\infty = \max_{1\le i \le N} |x_i-y_i|$$
(sometimes also called [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)), then you are done.

If you are using some other metric $d(x,y)$ it only remains to show that $d_\infty(x,y) \le C d(x,y)$ for some constant $C$. (Which is true for the commonly used metrics on $\mathbb R^N$.)

---

To see that the inequality marked $(*)$ holds you can argue as follows.

Let us assume that $\max x_i \ge \max y_i$. In this case we have $|\max x_i-\max y_i|=\max x_i-\max y_i$.

Let us denote by $i_0$ the index $i_0\in\{1,2,\dots,N\}$ such that $x_{i_0}=\max x_i$. Then we have
$$\max x_i-\max y_i = x_{i_0} - \max y_i \overset{(1)}\le x_{i_0} - y_{i_0} \le \max (x_i-y_i) \le \max |x_i-y_i|.$$
(The inequality $(1)$ holds since $y_{i_0} \le \max y_i$ and, therefore, $-\max y_i \le -y_{i_0}$.)

The case $\max y_i \ge \max x_i$ is symmetric.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $|\max x_i-\max y_i|\le \max|x_i-y_i|$? I think it might be related to something like $|\max(a_i+b_i)|\le \max |a_i|+\max|b_i|$, but how?

Comment: @Vim I have added a few lines to my answer.